# Symbol rate and bit rate for raised cosine

Tags: filters, digital-communications

Suppose I have a system transmitting at $8192 \ b/s$, using raised cosine with roll-off $\alpha = 0.5$. I am really confused if the symbol rate and the bit rate are the same for this case, i.e. $T_s = T_b = \frac{1}{8192} s$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ***can't*** tell that from the facts you're starting - neither the bit rate nor the pulse shape tell you what the constellation is you're using, and thus how many bits there are per symbol. And hence, you can't say what the symbol rate is.

Comment: I see your point. I guess either something is wrong with the statement of my homework or I'm misunderstanding it. If I were told that constellation has only two elements, then only under those conditions I can tell that $Ts = Tb$, right?